# Failed to install System.Win32.Com

Tags: winapi, haskell, gcc, com, cabal

I run virualized Windows 7 x64. Installation of [System.Win32.Com](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/com) package fails. How to cope the problem?

```
> cabal install com
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring com-1.2.3.1...
cabal: Bad header file: include/comPrim.h
The header file contains a compile error. You can re-run configure with the
verbosity flag -v3 to see the error messages from the C compiler.
Failed to install com-1.2.3.1
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
com-1.2.3.1 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Running with `-v3` option gives errors like these:

```
In file included from C:\Users\Leo\AppData\Local\Temp\282536868.c:3:0:
./include/comPrim.h:123:1: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or
'__attribute__' before 'OleInitialize'
OleInitialize ( void* pvReserved );
^
./include/comPrim.h:128:1: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or
'__attribute__' before 'OleUninitialize'
OleUninitialize ();
^
...
```

Moreover `-v3` option says that some packages cannot be found. Could it be the reason? I list only several of them.

```
Searching for ghcjs-pkg in path.
Cannot find ghcjs-pkg on the path
Searching for greencard in path.
Cannot find greencard on the path
```

`cabal` even doesn't know about some of them (for example `hmake`).

**Update on compiler**
GCC version output:

```
> gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\7.10.3\mingw\bin/realgcc.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/Program\ Files/Haskell\ Platform/7.10.3/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-5.2.0/configure --prefix=/mingw64 --with-local-prefix=/mingw64/local --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --with-native-system-header-dir=/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include --libexecdir=/mingw64/lib --with-gxx-include-dir=/mingw64/include/c++/5.2.0 --enable-bootstrap --with-arch=x86-64 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=c,lto,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --enable-shared --enable-static --enable-libatomic --enable-threads=posix --enable-graphite --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --disable-isl-version-check --enable-lto --enable-libgomp --disable-multilib --enable-checking=release --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/mingw64 --with-mpfr=/mingw64 --with-mpc=/mingw64 --with-isl=/mingw64 --with-pkgversion='Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project' --with-bugurl=http://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2 --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.2.0 (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project)
```

Comment: seems like the `comPrim.h` has syntax errors in it - if you know C/C++ you can try to download the source and fix it yourself - if not you should probably let the author know

Comment: The second half of the question I can answer -- cabal checks for lots of things that people may wish to use, even if they aren't asked for. -v3 is very verbose and shows that. So you can disregard that as far as I know, in terms of diagnosing the proximate errors :-)

Comment: On the first half, you need to make sure you're using the _right_ c compiler -- ideally the one tied to the mingw install that comes with ghc. You can pass that into cabal as an option, or just make sure your paths are all configured right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are building with an incompatible C compiler, e.g the `x86_64-w64-mingw32` toolchain
that is installed with [MinGHC installer for GHC 7.10.2 (64-bit)](https://www.haskell.org/downloads/windows).
It will produce the errors you are seeing. The `mingw32` that is installed with [MinGHC installer for GHC 7.10.2 (32-bit)](https://www.haskell.org/downloads/windows)
will not produce them.

Building the package with 32-bit GCC will mean that you can build it on 64 or 32 bit Windows and
it will execute on 64 or 32 bit Windows, but you cannot link 32-bit with 64-bit package libraries together.

That may be academic, however, as building this package (`cabal install com`) using the 32-bit
compiler just gets you as far as a later ghc compilation error:

```
[ 2 of 21] Compiling System.Win32.Com.HDirect.Pointer ( System\Win32\Com\HDirect\Pointer.hs, dist\build\System\Win32\Com\HDirect\Pointer.o )
*** Parser:
*** Renamer/typechecker:

System\Win32\Com\HDirect\Pointer.hs:102:20: Not in scope: `catch'
```

This after a variety of warnings for deprecated commandline options e.g.

```
on the commandline: Warning:
    -fglasgow-exts is deprecated: Use individual extensions instead

on the commandline: Warning:
    The -fvia-C flag does nothing; it will be removed in a future GHC release
```

and preprocessor directives, e.g.

```
System\Win32\Com.hs:1:12: Warning:
    -#include and INCLUDE pragmas are deprecated: They no longer have any effect
```

This package appears to have been ill-maintained.

Comment: Does it mean that the library can be built only for 32 bit platform?

Comment: I added `gcc -v` output to the question. And I had no another GCC version preinstalled. The only one is that comes with Haskell Platform

Comment: @Leonidas See revised answer.